# How to extract ref values from the elements of tag 'way' in osm file in java?

Tags: java, openstreetmap

I am going to extract ref values from a OSM file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmfilter 1.4.2">
    <way id="10053349">
        <nd ref="4534884733"/>
        <nd ref="4534884725"/>
        <nd ref="4534884748"/>
        <nd ref="82608659"/>
        <nd ref="82608658"/>
        <nd ref="639108039"/>
        <nd ref="3451083060"/>
        <nd ref="345553449"/>
        <nd ref="345553447"/>
        <nd ref="345553431"/>
        <nd ref="3451083057"/>
        <nd ref="345553432"/>
        <nd ref="345553433"/>
        <nd ref="345553434"/>
        <nd ref="345553435"/>
        <nd ref="3451083068"/>
        <nd ref="345553436"/>
        <nd ref="29564147"/>
        <nd ref="345553437"/>
        <nd ref="345553438"/>
        <nd ref="3451083079"/>
        <nd ref="345553439"/>
        <nd ref="3451083082"/>
        <nd ref="345553440"/>
        <nd ref="1326631485"/>
        <nd ref="82608663"/>
        <nd ref="82608662"/>
        <nd ref="4534884733"/>
        <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="21"/>
        <tag k="addr:street" v="Arcisstraße"/>
        <tag k="amenity" v="university"/>
        <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
        <tag k="name" v="1"/>
        <tag k="wheelchair" v="yes"/>
    </way>
</osm>
```

What I want at the end is to store ref values in a text file like:

```
4534884733
4534884725
4534884748
82608659
82608658
639108039
3451083060
.
.
```

Can anyone help me please? Is there any java code I can use to perform this task?

Comment: I removed the Perl and Python tags. Please don't tag spam... there's nothing here whatsoever that indicates this relates to any of those languages. Also, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You are required to post the code that you've tried, with a specific question on somewhere you're having issues with it. Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/57230/how-to-extract-node-reference-values-within-a-way-from-osm-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Xpath` :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("C://...//myFile.xml");

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//nd/@ref");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The pattern `"//nd/@ref"` will take all `nd` element and keep their `ref` attibute, you will be able next to read over them , `NodeList` is not iterable ou need to go throught like an array :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
    //write : nl.item(i).getTextContent(), somewhere
}
```

Comment: Please, don't encourage "please write the code for me" type questions.